# BASH Script to Remove old files, and create a text file containing the count and size of total files deleted.

Tags: linux, bash, shell, memory, memory-management

I am an Intern and was given a task of creating a BASH script to delete files in a directory older than 60 days and then exports a text file containing the number of files deleted as well as the amount of data removed. I am still attempting to learn BASH and have a one liner to remove files older than 30 days;

```
    `find $DIR -type f -mtime -60 -exec rm -rf {}\;`
```

I am still actively attempting to learn BASH, so extra notes on any responses would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I found [Bash Academy](http://guide.bash.academy/) , but looks like the site is incomplete, any recommendations for further reading in my quest to learn bash will also be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the below script, say **deleter.sh** for the purpose :

```
#!/bin/bash
myfunc()
{
  local totalsize=0
  echo " Removing files listed below "
  echo "${@}"
  sizes=( $(stat --format=%s "${@}") ) #storing sizes in an array.
  for i in "${sizes[@]}"
  do
  (( totalsize += i )) #calculating total size.
  done
  echo "Total space to be freed : $totalsize bytes"
  rm "${@}"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]  #$? is the return value
    then
  echo "All files deleted"
  else
    echo "Some files couldn't be deleted"
  fi
}
export -f myfunc
find "$1" -type f -not -name "*deleter.sh" -mtime +60\
-exec bash -c 'myfunc "$@"' _ {} +
# -not -name "*deleter.sh" to prevent self deletion
# Note -mtime +60 for files older than 60 days.
```

Do

```
chmod +x ./deleter.sh
```

And run it as

```
./deleter '/path/to/your/directory'
```

**References**

1. Find [[ manpage ]](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for more info.
2. `stat --format=%s` gives size in bytes which we store in an array. See [[ stat ]](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) manpage.

---

<sup>feedback appreciated</sup>

Comment: Nice :) Worth mentioning that `{} +` with find builds the command line

Comment: Thank you @sjsam, this is amazing, much cleaner than what I was working on, in case you may be interested here is what I came up with;
        #!/bin/bash
date=$(date +%F)
#Creates a text file with output of find command.
find -type f -mtime -60 > /tmp/$date.text
cp /tmp/$date.text /root
#Reads $date file, and removes the files listed within.  
xargs -a /tmp/$date.text -d'\n' rm

Comment: You'rs is much cleaner, and doesn't create the file that mine does. I have much to learn! Also, @mona_sax thanks you for the info!